# What is difference between two f# compiler projects

Tags: f#, compiler-construction

I want to learn f# compiler's internals. It turns out that there is two repositories on github. Here are links to these repos:

1. https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp
2. https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp

What is difference between these projects? Which should I use to learn compiler's design? I really cannot understand difference.

Comment: well, there is a readme

Comment: [Contributing to the F# Compiler, Core Library and Tools](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp#contributing-to-the-f-compiler-core-library-and-tools)

Comment: If you want to learn the compiler internals, I'd suggest going through the repository issues and trying to tackle a small one. Make a PR, and don't be afraid to ask questions in it -- the community there is super welcoming. Also, check out the F# Software Foundation slack channel!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is ownership.

The Microsoft repository is owned by Microsoft, and they're responsible for packaging F# with Visual Studio (hence "Visual F#").

The FSharp repository is owned by the F# Software Foundation, and is responsible for packaging F# for use on Linux, Android, iOS etc.

The compiler and tools are largely mirrored between the two repositories, but they aren't necessarily exactly the same at any point in time - see the  F# Core Engineering Group for details. New contributions go to the Microsoft repository, from which they are later replicated to the F#SF repository (so there's no divergence between the platforms - only a slight lag for the cross-platform stuff).

If you want more information about how the development of F# works, https://fsharp.github.io/2014/06/18/fsharp-contributions.html is a good place to start.

To answer more directly: use the Microsoft repository. You only need to care about the F#SF repository if you want to look at the specifics of the cross-platform implementations.